# From the nearest store from/of/near our house?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you have just bought a snack at £8 at store B(let's say).Then you were a bit surprised coz'...

> the same snack costs £10 from the nearest store **from/of/near** your house.

Which is the correct preposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually:

> The same snack costs £10 from **the nearest store to** your house.

But more naturally:

> The same snack costs £10 from **the store nearest to** your house.

Distance measurements generally use from/to.

And while you could write:

> The same snack costs £10 from **the nearest store near** your house.

this sounds awkward, and using words like near/far usually need a fixed reference, and "nearest store near your house" has too many variables as to location.

Comment: Nice nailed it, I need that phrase(the second highlighted sentence). Thx man.